# Using application wide single instance of service in angular2

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-services

I am making an Angular2 application. I have a login service class that is provided at the application level and is used by login component and authentication guard service.

If my understanding of DI is correct, once the service is provided at an application level through providers metadata of AppModule the same instance of the service is provided to all the components, when injected and hence the change to the member of the service class by one component will be reflected on the other service or component class.

I have provided the login service class in application level but changing the service's member variable from one component is not being reflected in other component. My login component changes the loggedIn variable to true, but when i access it from the auth guard service it is still getting the false value.

Following are my code snippets:

**AppModule**

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MyModule
],
providers: [
    AuthguardService,
    LoginService
],
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
],
exports: [
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**AuthguardService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginService } from './mymodule/login';

@Injectable()
export class AuthguardService implements CanActivate {

    constructor(
        private service: LoginService, 
        private router: Router
    ) { }
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean{
         let url: string = state.url;
         return this.checkLogin(url);
    }

    private checkLogin(url: string){
        debugger;
        if (this.service.isLoggedIn()) {
            console.log(this.service.loggedIn);
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log(this.service.loggedIn);
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**LoginService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    loggedIn: boolean = false;
    constructor(
        http: Http
    ){}

    login(username: string, password: string){
        let header = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        });
        return this.http.post(
            'http://localhost/api/login',
             JSON.stringify({login:username,password:password}),
             {headers: headers}).map((res: Response)=>{
                 this.loggedIn = true;
                 return res.json();
             })
             .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    logout(){
        this.loggedIn = false;
    }
    isLoggedIn(){
        if(this.loggedIn == true){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong here. When i call the login service from the login component the login is done successfully and the loggedIn variable is set to true but when i try to redirect it to other route and the AuthguardService uses login service the value of loggedIn is false. I have checked all the module class if there are multiple providers of the login service but there is not.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are  you re-create the service while redirecting it to other routes? Try to use singleton  design pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) to implement that service. Then it will create one object and return it to all requests. I think it will work. :)

Comment: i have read many posts about singleton service in angular2. They all say that angular2 uses HIERARCHICAL DEPENDENCY INJECTION, So if i have to use same instance of the service class I have to provide it at root level only and remove providers metadata from other modules and components which i have done. But i still cannot get the result.

Comment: please try loggedIn variable as static (static loggedIn: boolean = false). I thin it will work :)

Comment: i have already tried that too. Unfortunately that too does not work.

Comment: oh :( static variables belong to classes. so if you changed it in from one place. it should change for all places. I think the problem is not with your service class :/

Comment: FYI my auth guard is in the root level folder i.e 

`src>app>auth-guard.service.ts`

 and my login service is in 

`src>app>mymodule>login>login.service.ts`

. I am pretty new to angular2 so may be in file structure or something else could be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the way i submitted the form was the problem. I had called the `login()` method on the button click rather than the `(ngSubmit)` so when i click the login button, first the click event would fire and then the submit event. And the submit event was reloading the whole application causing it to make a new instance of everything. Always use `(ngSubmit)` event to submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

This may happen if you add your service in the providers array of any other component other than module.ts

Comment: Checked multiple times but i have not provided it anywhere else other than app.module.ts